# C# Crypt returning null

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method:

```
    public static string DecryptFile(string sInputFilename,
       string sKey)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

        FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
           FileMode.Open,
           FileAccess.Read);
        ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();

        CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread,
           desdecrypt,
           CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        return new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

This is the crypt method:

```
    public static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename,
       string sOutputFilename,
       string sKey)
    {
        FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename,
           FileMode.Open,
           FileAccess.Read);

        FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename,
           FileMode.Create,
           FileAccess.Write);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
        CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted,
           desencrypt,
           CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Close();
        fsInput.Close();
        fsEncrypted.Close();
    }
```

In the crypt file, i am putting string with commas that contains array.
Here is the code that pulling that data:

```
sSecretKey = Crypt.GenerateKey();
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(sSecretKey, GCHandleType.Pinned);

string data = Crypt.DecryptFile(dencrypt, sSecretKey);
Crypt.ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), sSecretKey.Length * 2);
gch.Free();

string[] arr = data.Split(',');
```

Now, after i am running it i am putting break point on line of the var and then i see that it's null and not containing anything..

Someone know what is the problem?

Comment: 1. Please [copy and paste the exception in to your answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx), 2. Which line does the error happen, 3. You should be disposing the objects that are disposable by [wrapping them in a using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) (`DESCryptoServiceProvider`, `FileStream`, `CryptoStream`, and `StreamReader` all need to be disposed)

Comment: What does the code that encrypts the file look like?

Comment: Also, when you answer my questins please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18618113/edit) with the information, not just leave a comment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ok. i added the method. it's not a stack error, i mean a break point that i putted in the line of the var..

Comment: You must loop over `fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);` [until it stops reading bytes](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/10/reading-all-bytes-from-a-stream.aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain but the EncryptFile method is works fine

Comment: It may "work" but it might not be reading all of your file in. I doubt it is causing your problem but if you ever read a file over a few K in size it will be a problem. Also why are you returning a string instead of a `byte[]` on your decrypt function are you always planning on only encrypting text files?

Comment: Also, you are breaking on the line of the function, has the function run yet? The variable will be null till the function returns, what is the value of the variable if you do a "step over"?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it's still null. the problem is when i am trying to decrypt it. `string data = Crypt.DecryptFile(dencrypt, sSecretKey);`

Comment: I tried the code, I also see its from the msdn example here (variable names are the same): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010 . The code works (both yours, and the example), but I would encourage you to dispose of the objects properly and also pay attention to Scott's advice. It's not the best implementation (msdn examples rarely are)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok. it's works. i think someone need to answer to this question and then i will Vote up and V it.